# Xcode 6.3 can't add new file to project

Tags: xcode, swift

Every time I add a new file to my project with File > new file, it appears red in project navigator, and I can't view the contents of the file. This wasn't happening in Xcode 6.2 a few minutes ago. Immediately started happening after I upgraded to Xcode 6.3.

Comment: Strange behaviour, I did not encountered this. - Did you close xcode before updgrading? - With xcode upgrade, did you apply _yosemite update_ too and _reboot_?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was when I was clicking new file, Xcode defaulted to adding the file in the "Documents" folder of my Mac for some reason...

I just had to make sure to select my project folder when adding the new file.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the default folder is always Documents still. I just always have to remember to change it to my project folder each time I add a file.